# Reading value of `stdout` and `stderr`

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am trying to read value of `stdout` and `stderr` using the following commands:

```
cat /dev/stderr

cat /dev/stdout
```

But, the command keeps running.

Comment: Is it generated by some command? or whose `stdout`, `stderr` are you trying to read here?

Comment: Is it true to say that `/dev/stderr` or `/dev/stderr` is like a file?

Comment: kindof, you may want to read up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams

Comment: What do you mean by "rhe value of" `stdout`? What kind of output do you expect?

Comment: when you type a command, like `echo "hello world"` the result of that command `hello world` is displayed on stdout.

Comment: If you actually need to **read** from `stdout` or `stderr`, then you must connect the streams to the **input** of another process, either by redirection or by *piping* the output to another command (e.g. `tee`, etc.)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Some of your explanation is right, but commands typically execute in the current shell, not a subshell, unless you invoke one. For example: `( command )` runs *command* in a subshell, but `command` by itself executes in the current shell.

Comment: Agreed, I was intending (inartfully) to explain the need to use the information being piped and used as input, but you are correct, calling `cat` directly executes in the *current* shell.

Comment: You misunderstand the streams. Both `stdout` (standard stream `1`) and `stderr` (standard stream `2`) are output streams and are attached to a process. When you run a command (e.g. `cat`) it begins execution without any information in either `stdout` or `stderr`. `cat` *concatenates* files (and by default will output the results on `stdout`) When you call cat it happily blocks waiting on some file to concatenate. You can redirect to either, but cannot `cat` either directly, e.g. `echo foo | cat - >/dev/stderr` (properly `echo foo >&2`)

Comment: You might be able to read from `stderr` as weird as it sounds. On Debian `cat /dev/stderr > somefile` or `read -u 2` work as well as if reading from stdin (but redirections of `stdin` of course don't affect reading from `stderr`...). Works on my OS X too, though that's about all I can test on, now.

Answer (score 2):

### Use a FIFO Instead

Technically, */dev/stdout* and */dev/stderr* are really file descriptors, not FIFOs or named pipes. On my system, they're actually just symlinks to */dev/fd/1* and */dev/fd/2*. Those descriptors are typically linked to your TTY or PTY. So, you can't really read from them the way you're trying to do.

What you probably want is the *mkfifo* utility. For example, to write to standard error, and then read it from another command or script:

```
# Create a named pipe.
$ mkfifo error

# See what a named pipe looks like in the filesystem.
$ ls -l error
prw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 May 13 01:47 error|

# In a subshell: echo to stdout, duplicate stdout to stderr,
# write stderr to the error FIFO. Background to avoid blocking.
# Then read from the FIFO until empty, which ends both tasks.
$ ( echo foo >&2 2> error & ); cat error
foo
```

As a more verbose but less contorted example, consider this:

```
$ ruby -e 'STDERR.puts "Some error."' 2> error & cat error
[1] 32458
Some error.
[1]+  Done                    ruby -e 'STDERR.puts "Some error."' 2> error
```

In this example, Ruby uses standard error to write a string to the *error* FIFO we created earlier. The write happens in the background, but blocks until the FIFO is emptied by the *cat* command. Once the FIFO is emptied, the background job completes.

The FIFO is just a special type of file, so you can remove it when you're done with `rm error`.

Comment: I think that `( echo foo >&2 2> error & )` has the redirections in the wrong order. That would redirect stdout to whatever stderr has (the terminal), and then redirect stderr to the pipe. The process still blocks when opening the pipe since there's no reader, but `cat` doesn't get anything from the pipe, it's just that starting it releases the `echo` to write to the terminal. Try with something `... | cat >/dev/null` or `... | cat -n`

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you mean by reading the value of `stderr` or `stdin`, but I can tell you why that `cat /dev/stderr` would keep running: it's waiting for data to read from the fd.

On the systems I can test this on, both output fd's are connected to the terminal just like `stdin` is, and reading from them works just fine. On Linux, we can view this with:

```
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd
lrwx------ 1 nobody nogroup 64 May 13 21:47 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 nobody nogroup 64 May 13 21:47 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 nobody nogroup 64 May 13 21:47 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 nobody nogroup 64 May 13 21:47 3 -> /proc/44664/fd
```

The permission bits at the start of the line show that all of the fd's 0 to 2 are opened for both reading and writing.

Reading from them works in practice, too (input in italics):

```
$ cat /dev/stderr
foo
foo
$ read -u 2 ; echo "reply: $REPLY"
asdf
reply: asdf
```

Though really, it might be better to just open `/dev/tty` and read from there if we want to interact on the terminal even when there are redirections in place. (That's what `ssh` does to ask the password, for example.)